# Find max and min of $x_1 y_1 + ...... + x_n y_n$ with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> Using Lagrange Multipliers, find the max and min of $$x_1 y_1 + ...... + x_n y_n$$ subject to constraints $$x_1^p + ...... + x_n^p = X^p$$ $$y_1^q + ...... + y_n^q = Y^q$$ with $\frac1p + \frac1q = 1$, (assuming $x_i \geq 0$ and $y_i > 0$ for all i).

I know the objective function $f(x) = x_1 y_1 + ...... + x_n y_n$, but I have no clue on how to transform $\frac1p + \frac1q = 1$ to constraints with x and y to apply Lagrange. (All I can think of is $x_1^{\frac1p}x_1^{\frac1q} y_1^{\frac1p}y_1^{\frac1q} + ......+ x_n^{\frac1p}x_n^{\frac1q}y_n^{\frac1p}y_n^{\frac1q} = x_1 y_1 + ...... + x_n y_n$, but I don't think it's relevant). I'm new to optimization and lagrangian so I really don't know how to proceed. Can I have some hints? Thank you so much.

Comment: $p$ and $q$ should be given rather than the variables to optimize. So you don't need to put that "constraint".

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm a bit confused about how to use Lagrange without constraints?

Comment: You have two constraint equations to use, don't you? But, yes, $p$ and $q$ are constants. You will use the equation relating them towards the end of your exploration.

Comment: Thanks! Yea the main problem is I don't know how to relate $\frac1p + \frac1q = 1$ to . Usually, the Lagrange constraints look like a $g(x) = c$ and we can naturally put this in the lagrange by $\lambda(g(x) - c)$, but I really don't know what g(x) is in this case.

Comment: You can start with the case $p = q = 2$ if that would make you feel better. Note that $(p, q)$ is just like $(2, 2)$: they are constants, satisfying a certain condition (like the $c$ in your example, they shall not be confused with the "constraint" for optimization variables.)